# Is there any difference between the free homotopy classes and homology classes of oriented loops in a closed oriented surface

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Is there any difference between the free homotopy classes and homology classes of oriented loops in a closed oriented surface $S$?

I know that the conjugacy classes of the fundamental group $\pi_1(S)$ are in one to one correspondence with the free homotopy classes of oriented loops in $S$. But the conjugacy classes of the fundamental group $\pi_1(S)$ are identified with the homology classes of loops in $S$. Therefore, free homotopy classes and homology classes of loops in $S$ are in one to one correspondence. So there is no difference if we say homology class or free homotopy class. Am I right?

Comment: Do you know about Hurewicz' theorem? (The one which relates $H_1$ and $\pi_1$.)

Comment: Take $T^2 \# T^2$. Then there is a loop representing where you took the connected sum. It is null-homologous but not freely null-homotopic.